# ROS-PCL point clouds

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We generate point cloud (points2) using ros and now we want to store it into pcd file so as to use that file into standalone PCL.
Is it possible to subscribe point-cloud through ROS and then further process it using standalone PCL??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12819/ros-pcl-point-clouds/) by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes its possible.
My answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/3782/point-clouds-in-ros#5918) should be of some help to you.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1